# Fixing firmware - Debian 8.5 fresh install on Toshiba Satellite

Tags: debian, firmware, iwlwifi, toshiba

I just installed Debian 8.5 CD install on my Toshiba Satellite machine, not in a VM. As it was setting up it told me that some `iwlwifi` and `rtl` files were missing, but it didn't really matter as I thought I could add them later.

Using a usb stick, I downloaded [firmware-iwlwifi](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/all/firmware-iwlwifi/download) and [firmware-realtek](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/all/firmware-realtek/download), used `dpkg -i` on both and my previously empty `/lib/firmware` is now populated with a lot of `iwlwifi` files and a directory `/lib/firmware/rltwifi` with quite a bit of `rlt` files.
After reboot, `ifconfig` still only listed `lo`.
Downloaded and installed `iwconfig` to see if I can wake up `wlan0` manually, but it still didn't work.

In the [Ask Ubuntu General Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) they asked me the output of `lsmod | grep iwlwifi`, which [showed](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30695065#30695065) that indeed I have the driver installed

`rfkill` wasn't installed, and after installation via USB no connection was blocked, but it had found an `hci0` and `phy0`

`dmesg | grep wifi` outputs (all under `[   some numbers] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0:`):

```
irq 66 for MSI/MSI-X
Unsupported splx structure
firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-3160-9.ucode
loaded firmware version 23.215.9.0 op_mode iwlmvm
Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3160, REV=0x164
L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
```

output of `lspci -nn | grep 0280`:
`07:00.0 Network Controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 [8086:08b3] (rev cb)`

I don't have a desktop environment yet, so only terminal answers please, althought it is possible to set up MATE or GNOME via USB

Is there anything I'm missing? Currently browsing from an old windows machine

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `lspci -nn | grep 0280`. Are you sure your card needs the `iwlwifi` driver?

Comment: @terdon done. Pretty sure, as it asked for those files on boot

Answer (score 1):

Install [network-manager](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/network-manager) , some dependencies need to be installed to get wifi working:

```
aptitude install network-manager
```

install the `wireless-tools`:

```
aptitude install wireless-tools
```

The right driver is installed according to your question.

*additional info : `iwlwifi` is a `non-free` firmware , it can be installed by adding a `non-free` to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` then run:*

```
aptitude install firmware-iwlwifi
```

Load the `iwlwifi` driver

```
modprobe -r iwlwifi ; modprobe iwlwifi
```

Add the following line to `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` and reboot:

```
options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0 swcrypto=1 11n_disable=8
```

bring up your wifi interface:

```
ip link set wlan0 up
```

Then run the following commands:

```
cp /usr/share/doc/wpasupplicant/examples/wpa-roam.conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

chmod 0600 /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Create `wpa_supplicant.conf`:

```
wpa_passphrase your-ssid-here your-passwd-here >> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

To scan use:`iwlist wlan0 scan` or `iw wlan0 scan` .

To connect run the following command:

```
wpa_supplicant -B -D wext -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
dhclient wlan0
```

Comment: aptitude doesn't seem to be a command. And assume I don't even have an ethernet connection

Comment: Edit , and add the output of `lspci | egrep -i  'network|ethernet'`

Comment: I ge both a network and an ethernet controller with no errors

Comment: The output will give the information about the needed driver to be installed to get the internet working.